# Why is np.sum not outputting anything?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I have two 2D arrays that are of the same size and I am trying to divide one by the other and then take the sum over one axis?
However I have a few nans from there being some division by zero, but when I try to square the divided arrays and then sum over one of the axis, I just get a blank plot:

```
east_rad = projections(np.real(inv_east_annual), 180)

rt_maha = projections(maha,180)

#dividing east_rad by rt_maha, rt_maha and east_rad both have shapes (1092, 180)

divide = east_rad/rt_maha

print(divide)

[[ 2.10160938e-17             nan -1.32855114e-02 ...             nan
  -1.24334979e-02             nan]
 [-2.59884274e-18 -6.19052022e-03 -1.11166036e-02 ... -1.27420254e-02
  -1.19839709e-02 -7.97509023e-03]
 [-1.34877182e-16 -5.03856340e-03 -5.29428667e-03 ... -1.80663486e-02
  -1.57691530e-02 -1.44670544e-02]


var = np.sum(divide**2,axis=0)

plt.plot(var)
plt.show()
```

[image: empty plot]

How do I fix this? So it actually shows a plot... or at least ignore the nans?

I also tried np.where(divide == np.nan, divide, 0), but I just get zeros!

Comment: have you tried printing var ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what it means in this case to divide by zero, but you could try

```
divide = east_rad/rt_maha
divide[np.isnan(divide)] = 0
```

To zero out your nans for plotting.

Comment: where do I mark this question correct on stackoverflow?

Comment: No idea :) also a stackoverflow noob. Clicking the upvote button might let you do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
divsq = divide**2
np.sum(divsq, where = ~np.isnan(divsq), axis = 0)
```

to ignore the `NaN` elements in the calculation of the sum.